# Solution of integral involving exponential and absolute values

Tags: integration, exponential-function, absolute-value

I want to solve this integral $\int_0 ^\infty e^{-iwx}e^{-α|x|} dx$

Any ideas on how to solve it?

Comment: Do you know how to use contour integrals from complex analysis?

Comment: No, unfortunately I don't

Comment: No need for contour integrals or even the absolute value.  $x \ge 0$ over the integration range.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\int_0 ^\infty e^{-iwx}e^{-\alpha|x|} dx = \int_0 ^\infty e^{-(iw  +\alpha) x } dx$$

Assuming that   $\Re(\alpha - iw)>0$ we write this integral as

$$\int_0 ^\infty e^{-(iw  +\alpha) x } dx = \int_0 ^\infty \frac{d (e^{-(iw  +\alpha) x })}{dx}  \frac{dx}{-(iw  +\alpha) } = \frac{1}{ iw  +\alpha}.$$

Answer (score 1):

$x \ge 0$ so we have that the integral is equal to

$$\int_0^{\infty} dx \, e^{-i w x} e^{- \alpha x} = \frac1{\alpha + i w} $$

(assuming $\alpha \gt 0$).

Comment: @ Ron How do you know $x \ge 0$? $e^{\mid x \mid}$ could be $e^{-x}$ or $e^{x}$.

Comment: @BLAZE: look at the integral limits.

Comment: Thanks that helped, wasn't paying attention to the limits, apologies and (+1)